# Getting exception while reading Connected property on TcpClient instance

Tags: c#, tcpclient

```
public bool IsConnected
{
    get { return _tcpClient == null ? false : _tcpClient.Connected; }
}
```

throws a

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

at

> at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.get_Connected()
>      at Project.ViewModel.ModbusOutputCounter.get_IsConnected() in C:...\ModbusOutputCounter.cs:line 115

How is this possible, and how can we prevent receiving this exception?

Edit:

as per svk's anwer the problem was in Disposing, which is internally called in Close() method. A workaround:

```
return _tcpClient?.Client != null ? _tcpClient.Connected : false;
```

Comment: it's definitely not in this line? post your code

Comment: @Rahul It is most definitely in that line. StackTrace shows only two methods, which I have posted.

Comment: Then it would appear that  `_tcpClient` is null.  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: @Tim If `_tcpClient` was `null`, the stack trace would not contain `get_Connected`. Because of that, I don't think this is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @svick - Fair enough.  I've retracted the close vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [reference source for `TcpClient`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs,22efae515d6f014f), `Connected` directly returns `Connected` of the underlying socket. This means that `Connected` will throw `NullReferenceException` when the socket is `null`. Though skimming the reference source, I found two cases when that can happen:

1. When the `TcpClient` has been `Dispose`d.
2. When you explicitly set the `Client` `Socket` to `null`.

Comment: Thanks, Close() method is internally calling Dispose(), so this is the reason why this was happening. Easy workaround was to check for _tcpClient?.Client != null ? _tcpClient.Connected : false;

Comment: I had the same problem as you, this seems to be a bug.